# Client-Side Dynamic Removal of <script> Tags in <head>

Tags: javascript, html, browser, aggregation

Is it possible to remove script tags in the `<head>` of an HTML document client-side and prior to execution of those tags?

On the server-side I am able to insert a `<script>` above all other `<script>` tags in the `<head>`, except one, and I would like to be able to remove all subsequent scripts.  I do not have the ability to *remove* `<script>` tags from the server side.

### What I've tried:

```
(function (c,h) {
  var i, s = h.getElementsByTagName('script');
  c.log("Num scripts: " + s.length);
  i = s.length - 1;
  while(i > 1) {
    h.removeChild(s[i]);
    i -= 1;
  }
})(console, document.head);
```

However, the logged number of scripts comes out to only 1, since (as @ryan pointed out) the code is being executed prior to the DOM being ready.  Although wrapping the code above in a `document.ready` event callback does enable proper calculation of the number of `<script>` tags in the `<head>`, waiting until the DOM is ready fails to prevent the scripts from loading.

**Is there a reliable means of manipulating the HTML prior to the DOM being ready?**

### Background

If you want more context, this is part of an attempt to consolidate scripts where no option for server-side aggregation is available. Many of the JS libraries being loaded are from a CMS with limited configuration options. The content is mostly static, so there is very little concern about manually aggregating the JavaScript and serving it from a different location.  Any suggestions for alternative applicable aggregation techniques would also be welcome.

Comment: Yes, as per the parameters that are passed into the anonymous function on the last line. `c = console; h = document.head`

Comment: So here is the problem: you have inserted a script into the page as the first script. Since js scripts fire once they are loaded (which is the reason for document.ready - make sure the document is fully loaded before the js fires) your script is running, finding just itself and finishing because `s.length` is 1 and `i` is already greater then it.

Comment: Try inserting it as the last script in the head. It should still fire before the rest of the dom is ready i.e. before the html is loaded. And it should also pick up the other scripts in the head. then have it remove all but the last so like `for(i = 0; i < s.length -1; i++)`

Comment: Have you tried my above comment. As for another way of doing it. You would have to use something outside of the dom of the page you want to load. With a chrome extension or firefox add-on. With a chrome extension I would use the chrome api to grab the incoming info on a url change, strip the <script> tags and then re-serve it to the page.

Comment: @ryan Your suggestion doesn't prevent the previous script tags from loading. The add-on/extension is not an option.

Comment: So far I can find a way to do it with a rather horrible hack for FireFox... however webkit browsers seem to be rather persistent... and I haven't even considered IE yet. Is an interesting question! :)

Comment: @pebbl Glad it caught your interest. I figured that it might come down to a browser-by-browser set of solutions. I certainly look forward to see what you've come up with.

Comment: Yep totally. Well all the nice cross-browser / "safe" methods really don't work. So it's definitely going to have to rely on targetted hacks. Dom mutations is a nice idea, but they all fire after the script has been evaluated... tbh, allowing javascript to mess around with the browsers execution of code is something I'm quite glad the useragents don't make too easy ;)

Comment: What browsers need to be supported? (requiring IE6 for instance might severly restrict your options). What is the goal? Prevent scripts from executing / modifying your page?

Comment: @RobW IE7 would be preferred, but if it's a good answer, I'm not going to reject it for not supporting that low. Indication of an *approach* which might be viable is more important than specific browser support in a given answer.  The point is to prevent the evaluation of the all scripts on a page by means of a script in the top of the `<head>` which might suppress or remove subsequent scripts.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Since you cannot prevent future `<script>` tags from evaluating (whenever the `</script>` tag has been found, the corresponding code of `<script>` is fetched and evaluated. `<script src>` will block a document from loading further till the source is fetched unless the `async` attribute is set), a different approach need to be taken.
Before I present the solution, I ask: What can prevent a script within a `<script>` tag from executing? Indeed,

1. Removal of `<script>` from the source code.
2. Adding a [Content Security policy](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/security/content-security-policy/) directive to block scripts from certain sources.
3. Triggering a (runtime) error.

1 is obvious, and 2 can be derived from the documentation, so I'll focus on 3. The examples below are obvious, and need to be adjusted for real-world use cases.

#### Proxying

Here's a general pattern for proxying existing methods:

```
(function(Math) {
   var original_method = Math.random;
   Math.random = function() {
       // use arguments.callee to read source code of caller function
       if (/somepattern/.test(arguments.callee.caller)) {
           Math.random = original_method; // Restore (run once)
           throw 'Prevented execution!';
       }
       return random.apply(this, arguments); // Generic method proxy
   };
})(Math);
// Demo:
function ok()    { return Math.random(); }
function notok() { var somepattern; return Math.random(); }
```

In this example, the code-blocker runs only once. You can remove the restoration line, or add `var counter=0;` and `if(++counter > 1337)` to restore the method after 1337 calls.

`arguments.callee.caller` is `null` if the caller is not a function (eg. top-level code). Not a disaster, you can read from the arguments or the `this` keyword, or any other environment variable to determine whether the execution must be stopped.
Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/qFnMX/

#### Deny setters / getters

Here's a general pattern for breaking setters:

```
Object.defineProperty(window, 'undefinable', {set:function(){}});
/*fail*/ function undefinable() {} // or window.undefinable = function(){};
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/qFnMX/2/

And getters, of course:

```
(function() {
    var actualValue;
    Object.defineProperty(window, 'unreadable', {
        set: function(value) {
            // Allow all setters for example
            actualValue = value;
        },
        get: function() {
            if (/somepattern/.test(arguments.callee.caller)) {
                // Restore, by deleting the property, then assigning value:
                delete window.unreadable;
                window.unreadable = actualValue;
                throw 'Prevented execution!';
            }
            return actualValue;
        },
        configurable: true // Allow re-definition of property descriptor
    });
})();
function notok() {var somepattern = window.unreadable; }
// Now OK, because 
function nowok() {var somepattern = window.unreadable; }
function ok()    {return unreadable;}
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/qFnMX/4/

And so on. Look in the source code of the scripts you want to block, and you should be able to create a script-specific (or even generic) script-breaking pattern.

The only downside of the error-triggering method is that the error is logged in the console. For normal users, this should not be a problem at all.

Comment: +1 Excellent analysis and presentation of the alternatives.  I'm going to play with this for a bit to see how difficult it is to get something generic working.

Comment: +1 nice idea... You'd also have to hope that there is something you could proxy at the start of the scripts though that would cause a runtime error... otherwise you'll have part of the script executed before it was stopped. This would be a very easy solution though if all the scripts relied on jQuery ready/load listeners (or something similar) - although I doubt that this question would have been asked if that were the case ;)

Comment: The content-security-policy directive is really interesting! not heard of this before...

Comment: @pebbl Although nice, it's not necessary that the script ends at the beginning. The interesting parts are usually network requests and output handling, which can be captured easily.

Comment: I'm choosing this as the *accepted* answer, even though I selected [@pebbl's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/12872102/570918) to award the bounty to. My reasoning is that I think this answer provides a broader overview of the problem at hand, and hence might be a better starting place for future StackOverflow users with similar questions.

Answer (score 8):

Right, had another *slightly less mad* idea than my first, but it does depend on exactly what control you have on being able to insert tags in the head of the pages:

#### requirement

Put simply, if you can insert a `<noscript>` tag like I have below before any of the `<script>` declarations in the head, and you can then append a `</noscript>` tag to the end of the head, along with the final script snippet - you should be able to do whatever you want with the markup between the noscript tags before it is written back to the page.

The nice thing about this approach is that script-disabled agents will just ignore and parse the markup, but script-enabled agents will store the content up *but not use it*... exactly what is needed.

#### implementation

Whilst this is designed to be used with the head, it could easily be used the same way in the body, although it would have to be a separate implementation. This is because it has to work with a balanced and complete node tree, due to the nature of tags *(unless you can manage to wrap the entire markup in noscript?!?)*.

#### Upsides/Downsides

It's not full-proof, because scripts can lie outside of the head and body tags - at least before they are parsed - but it seems to work pretty confidently on everything I've tested so far... *and* it doesn't rely on a smattering of randomly ajax-powered code that'll break at the first sign of a browser update ;)

Plus I also like the idea of script tags within noscript tags...

```
<head>
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<noscript id="__disabled__">
  <script src="jquery.js"></script>
  <title>Another example</title>
  <script>alert(1);</script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="core.css" />
  <style>body { background: #ddd; }</style>
</noscript>
<script>
(function(){
  var noscript = document.getElementById('__disabled__');
  if ( noscript ) {
    document.write(
      String(noscript.innerHTML)
        /// IE entity encodes noscript content, so reverse
        .replace(/&gt;/gi,'>')
        .replace(/&lt;/gi,'<')
        /// simple disable script regexp
        .replace(/<script[^>]*>/gi,'<'+'!--')
        .replace(/<\/script>/gi,'//--'+'>')
    );
  }
})()
</script>
</head>
```

Comment: Thanks :) hope it helps with your idea.

Answer (score 7):

You could try to use the [**DOM Mutation**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DOM_events#Common.2FW3C_events) events:

```
DOMAttrModified
DOMAttributeNameChanged
DOMCharacterDataModified
DOMElementNameChanged
DOMNodeInserted
DOMNodeInsertedIntoDocument
DOMNodeRemoved
DOMNodeRemovedFromDocument
DOMSubtreeModified
```

like so:

```
document.head.addEventListener ('DOMNodeInserted', function(ev) {
   if (ev.target.tagName == 'SCRIPT') {
       ev.target.parentNode.removeChild(ev.target);
   }
}, false);
```

Also you can try the new way of doing this through [MutationObserver](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/MutationObserver?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=DOM/DOM_Mutation_Observers)

Comment: this is cool, and i've used it before, but its not especially useful unless you never plan on having people using ie visit your website.  dom mutation is only implemented in chrome+safari as far as i'm aware.

Comment: +1 Very interesting; didn't know about these before.  I wonder, however, since none of those events are cancelable if the script is already executed at the point that the event is fired.

Answer (score 6):

Ok so I have yet to test any of this in Internet Explorer *(I doubt it'll work)*, and don't berate me for the horribleness of the hacks... I know ;) but it does seem to work in FireFox, Safari, Chrome and Opera on Mac OSX - the recent public releases of those useragents, at least. I'll see if I can improve it when I get access to a windows machine... although I don't hold much hope for IE.

```
(function(xhr,d,de){
  d = document;
  try{
    de = ((de = d.getElementsByTagName('html')[0]) 
      ? de : ( d.documentElement ? d.documentElement : d.body ));
    /// this forces firefox to reasses it's dom
    d.write('&nbsp;');
    /// make an ajax request to get the source of this page as a string
    /// this could be improved, I've just chucked it in as an example
    if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
      xhr = new window.XMLHttpRequest;
    }else{
      xhr = new ActiveXObject("MSXML2.XMLHTTP");
    }
    if ( xhr ) {
      /// open non-async so the browser has to wait
      xhr.open('GET', window.location, false);
      xhr.onreadystatechange = function (e,o,ns){
        /// when we've got the source of the page... then
        if ((o = e.target) && (o.readyState == 4) && (o.status == 200)) {
          /// remove the script tags
          window.ns = ns = String(o.responseText)
              .replace(/<script[^>]*>/gi,'<'+'!--')
              .replace(/<\/script>/gi,'//--'+'>');
          /// fix for firefox - this causes a complete 
          /// rewrite of the main docelm
          if ( 'MozBoxSizing' in de.style ) {
            de.innerHTML = ns;
          }
          /// fix for webkit, this seems to work, whereas 
          /// normal document.write() doesn't. Probably 
          /// because the window.location resets the document.
          else {
            window.location = 'javascript:document.write(window.ns);';
          }
        }
      };
      xhr.send({});
    }
  }
  catch(ex){}
})();
```

Just to say I've tested this with nearly every type of script tag I can think of, placed where ever I could place them. And I haven't yet had one manage to break through. As I said, fun question... although I don't know how well the above would operate in a production environment :S ;)

Basically this will have to be placed as a script tag right at the top of the head tag.

A test example:

http://pebbl.co.uk/stackoverflow/12748067.html

Comment: Mother of god... good one xD I fear this hacks because they usually pop up again when you try to do a normal thing one month ago

Comment: Yeah :) as I said... I wouldn't rely on it myself at all... it would only take firefox to start ignoring the first `document.write()` *(as the other browsers do)* and the js would break through again. If it's only for script aggregation though - rather than removal - it could be a possibility... However aggregation is usually done as an optimisation, and calling the page source twice *(unless heavily cached)* isn't going to be optimal.

Comment: +1 Definitely an interesting and clever approach! I would have never thought of re-requesting the page and then overwriting the document with a filtered response.  But, also agreed about the viability of ever using this in production.  Nevertheless, you've got the best answer thus far; I'm still waiting to see if any others have alternatives.

Comment: @merv Thanks, heh, yeah no worries.. there may yet be a far more sane client-side alternative out there. With regards to not having control on the server side... is it not possible for you to create a .htaccess rerouter - or something similar? .. along the lines of what Drupal or an MVC system would do. Any request on the server gets routed through an index that pulls in the code for the actual page being requested, traps the output using some form of buffer and then strips/aggregates the script tags/scripts before sending on to the user?

Answer (score 1):

No you can't

I cannot find official documentation right now, but as I'm reading on [High Performance Javascript](http://www.amazon.es/Performance-JavaScript-Faster-Application-Interfaces/dp/059680279X) from [Nicholas Zakas](http://www.nczonline.net/), when the render engine founds a Tag script, it stops HTML rendering (so no other node is created), downloads the script and executes it. Then it continues rendering the HTML. That's why when you execute "document.write()" on a tag, the result is added JUST after the tag, then the rest of the page is rendered.

(I don't know if I can insert a paragraph of the book here...)

So it's not like rendering the page, then you remove the node and the script wont be executed, when the browser founds a  tag you cannot do anything until this code is executed.

We had a very similar problem at our product, we added a script tag to the DOM and we needed some code to be executed JUST before the new tag execution starts, after a week of research we had to find another solution.

Sorry, but I hope you don't waste so much time as we did. Anyway I'll keep looking for browser specification.