# How to preprocess HTML before it is parsed by the browser - block resorce loading

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am looking for a way to modify some text inside the HTML before it is being parsed by the browser.
More precisely, I would like to remove some  tags from the HTML so the image resources would not be fetched by the browser, only when I am ready I could insert these  tag back to have them loaded.
Is it possible to do that via some JS/Jquery or CSS, if so, how?

the motivation here is to be able to block the loading of some resources on a page and have them loaded only when needed according to some logic. this needs to be done by some kind of scripting added to the page

Comment: I'm guessing there's no magical way to do it, judging by how various lazy load plugins do it, for example http://www.appelsiini.net/projects/lazyload requires you to change your HTML: `<img data-original="img/example.jpg" src="a-placeholder.png">`

Answer (score 2):

Because you're doing this in JavaScript the HTML is already being processed when it comes to launch your `<script>` tags.

You could move your `<script>` tags into the `<head>` from the `<body>`, or move it to the very beginning of the body. However the problem here is that you'll have to wait for your elements to actually be created in the DOM before you can work with them.

You could use something like `setTimeout()` or similar and continually look for them until you find them, but there's still going to be a slight delay between them being created and your script finding them, at which point they might already start to load.

The only surefire way is to process the markup server side long before it gets to the browser.

Comment: Also note that if you put your JS code at the beginning of your HTML (head or body) it will be loaded before the page. If your script is heavy then it will take loading time with nothing visually happening for the user. That is a bad point for the user experience. I highly recommend you work on the server side...

Answer (score 1):

My answer here possibly could be of use, if you can place `noscript` tags in key places in your markup prior to parsing/evaluation:

[Client-Side Dynamic Removal of <script> Tags in <head>](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12748067/client-side-dynamic-removal-of-script-tags-in-head#answer-12872102)

This method—for javascript-enabled agents—would delay the rendering of the entire page however, or at least the regions that you needed to affect.

#### basic generalised theory

Wrapper your body or specific region with a `noscript` tag identified with either a class or id. Place some javascript to execute directly after the close `noscript` that grabs the tag and reads the html contents as a string. At this point you could modify the html string however you like and then re-inject it back into the DOM replacing the `noscript` tag.

#### more specific implementation

If you know before-hand which resources you need to postpone—say all your images—you could wrap each image in-question with a `noscript` tag. Then trigger off some JavaScript that grabs all `noscripts` and rewrites the contained image html to use a placeholder or lower quality version of the image. At the same time you could set up event listeners or timeouts that inject the actual images when the time is right.

Answer (score 0):

The [Lazy Load Plugin for jQuery](http://www.appelsiini.net/projects/lazyload) is maybe what you are looking for. It delays loading of images in long web pages.

You can use any jQuery event such as click or mouseover. You can also use your own custom events such as foobar. Default is to wait until user scrolls down and image appears on the window.

Beside all the It is also possible to delay loading of images. Following code waits for page to finish loading (not only HTML but also any visible images). Five seconds after page is finished images are loaded automatically.

```
$(function() {          
    $("img:below-the-fold").lazyload({
        event : "sporty"
    });
});
$(window).bind("load", function() { 
    var timeout = setTimeout(function() {
       $("img.lazy").trigger("sporty");
    }, 5000);
});
```

Check the [delayed loading demo](http://www.appelsiini.net/projects/lazyload/enabled_timeout.html).